# What does MPI calls does when running an MPI application as MPI Singleton?

Tags: c++, copy, mpi

As written [here](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.0/mpi-20-html/node112.htm), it is recommended that any MPI implementation should run without any problem if ever not run with an "MPI environment".

It is specified that if there is no "MPI environment", MPI_Init will build a size-1 MPI_COMM_WORLD with a MPI proc of rank 0.

My questions are :

1. What would then be the behavior of `MPI_Reduce(&send_buf,&recv_buf,size_buf,MPI_TYPE,MPI_OP,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD)` ? Will it actually copy the data from the send_buf to the recv_buf ? Or will it actually do nothing at all ?

I've tried it with openmpi-4.1.0, and it indeed copy the data. Here is the simple code I used :

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int IdProc,NbProc;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&IdProc);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&NbProc);

  int ToBeSend, ToBeRecv;
  ToBeSend = 57;

  MPI_Reduce(&ToBeSend,&ToBeRecv,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  std::cout << ToBeRecv << std::endl;

  MPI_Finalize();
  
  return 0;
}
```

I expect that all "good" implementation of the MPI standard would do so.

2. Is it actually the case ? Do I need to try a the few major ones my self ? (mpich, intel MPI, MSMPI...)

Comment: `./a.out` (singleton mode) and `mpirun -np 1 ./a.out` (non singleton mode) should have the same behavior. If they don't this is likely a bug.